# Should I reindex documents in elasticsearch when I update settings of index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I've read the re-indexing documents which is required if anything has been changed in the existing index then I've to re-index documents. 
For example. If I make a change in the existing field then I've to reindex all the documents.

Should I re-index documents if I make a change in settings of an existing index?

What if I want to add a new analyzer/filter in the settings? Does it require to re-index documents?

Comment: "Should i reindex documents in elasticsearch whem i update settings of index" - Yes , if you won't do that you will get different results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896418/elasticsearch-indicesclient-put-settings-not-working/58898505#58898505

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily, for example, changing shard number definitely requires a reindex, b/c ES needs to reshard all document. 
changing replicas doesn't need reindex, and in fact a common practice to speed up your index with replica = 0, then later turns it = 1.