# Query Elasticsearch index for words with and without accent

Tags: elasticsearch

I query for the word "café" and get 20 articles. Then I repeat the search for the word "cafe" and will only get 3 articles. So I'm looking for a possibility to handle words with letters with accent in the same way like words with letters without accent.
My problem is also, that I already have a filled index so I have to modify an existing system. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.5.

I found some useful information and went through the following steps:

Setting up folding analyzer

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user <user:pass> -XPUT http://localhost/test/_settings?pretty -d '{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "folding": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Modify existing mapping for the content field

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user <user:pass> -XPUT http://localhost/test/mytype/_mapping -d '{
  "properties" : {
    "content" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "folded" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "folding"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Do the search

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --user <user:pass> -XGET http://localhost/test/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "cafe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size" : 10,
  "from" : 0
}'
```

But it's the same effect like before: I only find the articles with "cafe", not also the articles with "café". Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! You have created a new analyzer and changed your mapping, however, you also now need to reindex your data in order to fill in the new `content.folded` field.

You can do it very easily by calling the [update by query endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-update-by-query.html#picking-up-a-new-property) like this:

```
curl --user <user:pass> -XPOST http://localhost/test/_update_by_query
```

Answer (score 0):

In  your search query you should mention `content.folded`, `folding` analyzer is assigned to `content.folded` and not `content`.

After a `mappings` update you will have to reindex your data in order to apply the change.

Reindex step by step [Reindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896418/elasticsearch-indicesclient-put-settings-not-working/58898505#58898505)

A working example:

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "folded": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "folding"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Inserting few documents**

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "content":"café"
}

POST my_index/_doc/2
{
  "content":"cafe"
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content.folded": "cafe"
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.18232156,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "café"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.18232156,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "cafe"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What he did is right, he just needs to make sure all the data is updated/reindexed first prior to running any queries so that the `content.folded` field is indexed as well.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make sure he knows he should use `content.folded`. He is using `query_string` without `default field`, meaning the default value is `*`.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense, though searching on all fields as he does would work, too.

Comment: Of course, it will work but it's not best practice. and the `bool` is unnecessary here.